# R plots not showing any labels

Tags: r, linux

When I make plots on R, I get the following:

[image: Text]

What is going on here? How do I get plot labels to properly display? This occurs both through jupyter notebook and if I write the plot to a file from an R script.

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Here is my R.Version() output:

```
$platform
'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu'

$arch
'x86_64'

$os
'linux-gnu'

$system
'x86_64, linux-gnu'

$status
''

$major
'3'

$minor
'6.1'

$year
'2019'

$month
'07'

$day
'05'

$`svn rev`
'76782'

$language
'R'

$version.string
'R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)'

$nickname
'Action of the Toes'
```

Here is my sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
[1] C.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1  IRdisplay_0.7.0 pbdZMQ_0.3-3    tools_3.6.1   
[5] htmltools_0.4.0 pillar_1.4.3    base64enc_0.1-3 crayon_1.3.4  
[9] Rcpp_1.0.3      uuid_0.1-2      IRkernel_1.1    jsonlite_1.6.1
[13] digest_0.6.24   repr_1.1.0      rlang_0.4.4     evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: This is most likely a "locale" thing. Can you include the output from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Yes - I have edited my post to include this

Comment: Maybe a fonts issue, possibly complicated by jupyter rendering. Does it do the same thing from command-line R?

Comment: Upon testing command-line R using `> pdf(); plot(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)); dev.off();`, I can confirm that it does not do the same thing and that indeed prints out plot labels as expected. I also see that command-line locale is different under `sessionInfo()` and contains the following:


`locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       

 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   

 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          

[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

Comment: I should clarify the statement "This occurs both through jupyter notebook and if I write the plot to a file from an R script" in my original post. I find that making a plot through ggplot2 and using ggsave to save the plot will result in the same character issue, even when I'm running an R script via command line. However, that might be a separate issue from making a basic plot.

Comment: Update: I tried using `Sys.setlocale` in jupyter to match the jupyter locale to the command-line locale, and it doesn't seem to have fixed it. The display for locale in `sessionInfo()` doesn't seem to change in Jupyter even when `Sys.setlocale` executes without error.